# Displaying only the current category in template page

Tags: post-type

I'm having a problem displaying filtered category list pages. I want to be able to only show the current category, not all of the posts from "my categories". i.e. www...com/mycategories/category-3/ would only show posts in category page. Here is what I have but it seems to display all the categories in the `taxonomy-mycategories.php` page.

**Template page:**

```
  <?php 
            $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;
            $temp = $wp_query;
            $wp_query= null;
            $wp_query = new WP_Query();
            $wp_query->query("post_type=business&category_name=" . $_GET["category"] . "&". $catinclude ."&paged=".$paged.'&showposts=20'); 
            if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php the_title() ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

**`functions.php:`**

```
/******************
//  Business
******************/

function my_custom_post_business() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'business', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'business', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New business' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit business' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New business' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All business' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View business' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search business' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No business found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No business found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'business'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our business and business specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'business',
            'with_front' => false
            ),
        //'taxonomies' => array('category'),
    );
    register_post_type( 'business', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_business' );



/** add categories for custom post type */
add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );
function build_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy( 'mycategories', 'business', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Business Categories', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean archive page rather then template page? Where multiple taxonomy types are displayed together.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
<?php
if (have_posts()):
    while (have_posts()):
        the_post();
?>


<h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
<?php
        if ($content != 'no') {
            the_excerpt();
        }
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: sorry maybe I wasn't clear in my explanation. My post type is business and I need to dynamically get the category. So if I am on main category page and filter down into a single category by clicking "My first category" I would like posts to only show from "My first category" which I believe to be stored in "taxonomy-mycategories.php" but I could be mistaken.

Comment: I updated my code and use it in your taxonomy-mycategories.php

Comment: still doesn't seem to work :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I clearly understand your question, but if you need to display the childs posts of a category on the category page, you ca use `get_posts` with the right arguments I believe :

In you *category-{id}.php* template :

```
    $args = array(
    'category'          => get_queried_object_id(), // Current category id
    'category__in'      => array( get_queried_object_id() ), // Only posts direct childs of the current category
    'orderby'           => 'post_date',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
);
$cat_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit hard to understand exactly what you want but why can't you use [pre_get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and customize the [conditionals](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cpt_portfolio_items' );
function cpt_portfolio_items( $query ) {

if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'business' ) ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '1' );
    }

}
```

Or something like this if i really understood exactly what you want

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'tax_portfolio_items' );
function tax_portfolio_items( $query ) {

if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_tax( 'tax-name' ) ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '1' );
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your explanations are still far from clear. Is this what you want? Assuming the code goes into the category.php page.

```
<?php

$cat = get_query_var('cat'); // get current category
$yourcat = get_category($cat);

// now get all 'business' posts that are in the current custom taxonomy 
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'business', 'mycategories' => $yourcat->slug ) ); 

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
  <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**Note:** untested code.

Comment: maybe this will be more clear: http://www.ottawakent.com/news/business-feed/ when you click "category 1" you only get posts that are in that category which should be the first post. I have your code currently implemented and it seems to pull all the posts in the custom post type and not the specific category.

Comment: Don't use query_posts